# Unable to install Force.com plugin IDE getting error

Tags: force.com, eclipse, force.com-ide

I am getting error While installing Force.com plugin to Eclipse.Error is

"Unable to connect to repository http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/content.xml
Connection timed out: connect "

[image]

Comment: are working within a firewall? Make sure your firewall allows you to connect to Force.com IDE

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading Eclipse classic Standard/SDK and update to salesforce plugin with  http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42. It worked for me.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-helios.php
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-42/junor

Answer (score 0):

[image]

AS you can find in image , you should use 
http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/
only "/" is missing at the end of url.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to install the plugin please follow below steps.
You should able to install force.com IDE plugin.
[image]

Click on 0 matches, Browse for more solutions link, you will get salesforce IDE and other supported plugin as shown 
[image]

Drag install icon in Project Explorer panel. You will get plugin screen.
Click on Confirm and finish. You should able to see plugin
[image]